# inner join with two selects sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

I am trying to implement an inner join to compare values of two tables, however failing for some reason and the query is returning zero columns.

I have two tables security and security_his and trying to join them on columns SECURITY_ID and INVESTMENT_OBJECTIVE. Query is as follows

```
SELECT *
FROM SECURITY origin
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM SECURITY_HIS t2
    WHERE DATED = (
            SELECT MAX(DATED)
            FROM SECURITY_HIS t1
            WHERE t1.SECURITY_ID = t2.SECURITY_ID
            )
    ) history ON origin.SECURITY_ID = history.SECURITY_ID
    AND origin.INVESTMENT_OBJECTIVE = history.INVESTMENT_OBJECTIVE;
```

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Comment: The query looks ok, probably  You dont have matching data. Check the result of the inner select `SELECT *
    FROM SECURITY_HIS t2
    WHERE DATED = (`

Comment: it is sqlServer and i have matching data! There should be something wrong with query

Comment: Show us schema and sample data or prepare a sqlFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/860c2

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza added schema

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza and here is the data! just removed username.

Comment: sorry your `create table` doesnt have the correct sintaxis, I cant create the table. Please fix it or try to create the sqlFiddle

Comment: @user1200279 if this is Sql-Server, why did you retag as Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT S.*,
           row_number() over 
               (partition by S.SECURITY_ID ORDER BY SH.DATED DESC)
    FROM SECURITY S
    JOIN SECURITY_HIS SH
      ON S.SECURITY_ID = SH.SECURITY_ID
     AND S.INVESTMENT_OBJECTIVE = SH.INVESTMENT_OBJECTIVE
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Then the problem is with your data, can you prepare the sql fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/ for me?

Comment: i exported the data but for some reason it is giving syntax error with that export

Comment: I know I try to load and didnt work, are you sure  is SQL Server? in sql fiddle is a function `Text to DDL` you just copy the data with fieldname and he will create the table for you.

Comment: I dont see fields `DATED` or `INVESTMENT_OBJECTIVE `

Comment: Still not complete only one table and not data :(

Comment: i update the question with the right inserts for those tables.

Comment: is that fine? let me know

Comment: Isnt fine. And sorry for more I would like to help, I cant fix table for you.

Comment: you cant insert them? what is the issue? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Give me an error, I try insert into my own sql server and didnt work. Missing `,` or missing `'`

Comment: You create the fiddle with oracle db?

Comment: you tried with the new inserts that i updated in the question? because i just tried it on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c789f/2 and it worked.

Comment: LOL, why you change it and didnt told me? Yes now is working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/699b4/6

Comment: lol i told you in the comments above "ok use this one with oracle sqlfiddle.com/#!4/699b4 ". All good we passed step one :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95746/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-user1200279).

Answer (score 0):

You have no GROUP BY on the innermost query, so only a single value, maxed over the entire table, is returned. However your query can also be simplified for easier understanding:

```
SELECT origin.*, history.Dated
FROM SECURITY origin
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        SECURITY_ID,
        INVESTMENT_OBJECTIVE,
        MaxDated = MAX(DATED)
    FROM SECURITY_HIS t2
    GROUP BY
        SECURITY_ID,
        INVESTMENT_OBJECTIVE
) history ON origin.SECURITY_ID          = history.SECURITY_ID
         AND origin.INVESTMENT_OBJECTIVE = history.INVESTMENT_OBJECTIVE
```

Comment: got syntax error on MaxDated = MAX(DATED)   ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 18

Comment: @user1200279: Don't use tag `sql-server` if your engine is Oracle. then. I can't read your mind or your error messages.